# how to add action to arraylist item in listview and how to get its position?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

Hi I am working with android.I had created a listview using array list. Now how can I add Action to each list item and also how to get the list position of that item. Please help me, thanks

here is my code

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {


          private ListView lv;

     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("aaaa");
        list.add("bbbb");
        list.add("cccc");
        list.add("dddd");

         ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, 
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
              list);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 


        }


     }
```

Comment: Refer to this link : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement `ListView setOnItemClickListener`

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {

       // ListView Clicked item index
               int itemPosition     = position;

               // ListView Clicked item value
               String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                  .show();
    }
        });
```

For more information go to [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the selected item of ListView in setOnItemClickListener using following code:

```
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            int itemPosition     = position;
            String itemname = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item: " + itemname + " is at position: " + itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the listview cells position and the index of arraylist are same. So we can easily get the item from arraylist by the position of cell of listview.

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
        {

             int position=position;
             String item=marraylist.get(position).toString();
         }
}
```