# How to pass multiple ArrayList to BaseAdapter in Android?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, baseadapter

I am trying to pass some dynamic data to `BaseAdapter` to display it on `listview` .(using `ArrayList`),My current code gives me following error:

Error:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable ArrayList
error: cannot find symbol variable String
```

Pointing to this part of code(ArrayList < String >):

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ArrayList<String> NameArrayList, ArrayList<String> IconArrayList);
```

I check the Arraylist size and foundout that IconArrayList and NameArrayList are not empty using int itemCount = IconArrayList.size();

However If i pass following static string array to Baseadapter then it displays the data on listview!

```
String NameArrayList[] = {"USA", "China", "australia", "Portugle", "Norway", "NewZealand"};
String IconArrayList[] = {"http://awebsite.com/icons/usa.png", "http://awebsite.com/icons/china.png", "http://awebsite.com/icons/australia.png", "http://awebsite.com/icons/portugle.png", "http://awebsite.com/icons/norway.png", "http://awebsite.com/icons/new_zealand.png"};

CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), NameArrayList, IconArrayList);
```

Could you guys help me fix above errors and pass arraylist successfully to baseAdapter so it displays it.Thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendGetRequest();

     }


public String sendGetRequest() {

         String NEW_ICON = "icon";


        ArrayList<String> IconArrayList =new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> NameArrayList =new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> UrlArrayList =new ArrayList<String>();


        try {

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new Builder().permitAll().build());

            HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://awebsite.com/test/test.php").openConnection();


            myURLConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
            myURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "html");
            myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0;)");

            OutputStream os = myURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            os.close();

            myURLConnection.connect();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));


            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line;


            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\\n");
            }
            in.close();



            String linesArray[] = sb.toString().split("#MYLIST:");

            for (int i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
                String currLine = linesArray[i];


                String[] dataArray = currLine.split(",");

                if (dataArray[0].contains(NEW_ICON)) {

                   String s =dataArray[0];

                    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1);
                    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(")"));


                    IconArrayList.add(s);



                    if (dataArray[1].contains("http://")) {
                        String[] split = dataArray[1].split("http://");
                        String name = split[0];
                        String url = split[1];
                        url ="http://"+url;

                        //adding name and url to arraylist
                        NameArrayList.add(name);
                        UrlArrayList.add(url);
                      }


                }



            }// end of for loop

            //showing array list total
            int itemCount = IconArrayList.size();
            int itemCount2 = NameArrayList.size();
            int itemCount3 = UrlArrayList.size();


            ListView simpleList;
            simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
            CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ArrayList<String> NameArrayList, ArrayList<String> IconArrayList);
            simpleList.setAdapter(customAdapter);


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;

    }
```

BaseAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    String countryList[];

    String flags[];

    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] countryList, String[] flags) {
        this.context = context;
        this.countryList = countryList;
        this.flags = flags;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countryList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);
        TextView country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        country.setText(countryList[i]);

        Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                .load(flags[i])
                //.resize(50,50)
                .into(icon);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are sending **`WRONG TYPE`**

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ArrayList<String> NameArrayList, ArrayList<String> IconArrayList);
```

**It will be**

```
 CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),  NameArrayList,  IconArrayList);
```

So, Your **`Constructor`**  will be

```
ArrayList<String> countryList;
ArrayList<String> flags;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext,ArrayList<String> countryListOBJ, ArrayList<String> flagsOBJ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.countryList = countryListOBJ;
        this.flags = flagsOBJ;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }
```

**Then**

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countryList.size();
    }
```

Comment: Tjhanks for all the replies. IntelliJ Amiya i tried your post but i get 3 new erros all pointing in lines inside custom adapter! error: cannot find symbol variable length
error: array required, but ArrayList<String> found
error: array required, but ArrayList<String> found

Comment: @user1788736 use `countryList.size()` instead of `countryList.length`

Comment: Now i get this error :error: array required, but ArrayList<String> found pointing to this line country.setText(countryList[i]); and .load(flags[i])

Comment: now it complains about setText :error: cannot find symbol variable setText

Comment: @user1788736 mine mistake, `country.setText(countryList.get(i))`

Comment: unfortunately no data is displayed on listview but no error while compiling! is there away to find out why no data was displayed on listview ?

Comment: @user1788736 print `countryList.size()` . Check result.

Comment: Many thanks for helping me i accepted your answer. Now data is displaying on listview :-)

Comment: if i want to display toast by clicking listview item how to refrence the listview row item inside simpleList.setOnItemClickListener ?

Comment: @user1788736 yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427469/how-to-add-action-to-arraylist-item-in-listview-and-how-to-get-its-position

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way to pass multiple properties to any class . Instead of it you should use a **POJO** class. Below is an example .

```
class CountryModel{
    public String countryName;
    public String countryFlag;

    public CountryModel(String countryName, String countryFlag) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.countryFlag = countryFlag;
    }
}
```

Then parse your data into a collection of this model objects.Below is an example.

```
 ArrayList<CountryModel> countryList=new ArrayList<>();
 countryList.add(new CountryModel("Norway","NorwayflagUrl"));
 countryList.add(new CountryModel("Iceland","IcelandflagUrl"));
 countryList.add(new CountryModel("Denmark","DenmarkflagUrl"));
```

Then set the adapter. In this case you need to modify your adapter.

```
ListView simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), countryList);
        simpleList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

You can modify your adapter as below.

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
   ArrayList<CountryModel> countryList;

    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<CountryModel> countryList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.countryList = countryList;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return countryList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);
        TextView country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        country.setText(countryList.get(i).countryName);

        Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                .load(countryList.get(i).countryFlag)
                //.resize(50,50)
                .into(icon);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** You used String array on `CustomAdapter` 's `constructor`. But you passed `ArrayList<String>` from `Activity` class. So make these `ArrayList` on `CustomAdapter`-

```
    private ArrayList<String> NameArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> IconArrayList;

    public CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ArrayList<String> NameArrayList, ArrayList<String> IconArrayList) {
        this.NameArrayList= NameArrayList;
        this.IconArrayList= IconArrayList;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }
```

**2.** You are fetching data from server by API call on `MainThread`. Try to keep this part on separate Thread for better performance (Some times you would not get any data from server for slow connection or large processing time). And Use Handler for communication  between these Threads Because you need to detect when finish api call and get data successfully. **OR You can use any third party [AndroidNetworking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) library for Thread safe network call.**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. do you mean i should use AsyncTask to fetch the api data ?

Comment: Yes, You can use `AsyncTask` aslo.  But thrid party library will be very easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

1.change

CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ArrayList NameArrayList, ArrayList IconArrayList);

to this

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),  NameArrayList,  IconArrayList);
```

2.change

```
 @Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}
```

to this

```
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}
```